# bAutoWidth:true scrolls the page to the top on datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

After my webpage loaded on mobile and when I scroll the page to the bottom quickly **bAutoWidth: true,** javascript code scrolls the page to the top in that time.

If I set false and change **bAutoWidth:false** there is no problem. But I need **bAutoWidth:** is true. Any alternate of **bAutoWidth:** ? 
**any suggestions?**

here is javascript that I used

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('table.table tfoot th').each(function () {
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="'+$(this).text()+'" />');
    });

    // DataTable
    var table = $('table.table').DataTable({

    order: [
          [7, "desc"]
        ],
    "language":{
    "sDecimal":        ",",
    "sEmptyTable":     "Tabloda herhangi bir veri mevcut değil",
    "sInfo":           "_TOTAL_ kayıttan _START_ - _END_ arasındaki kayıtlar gösteriliyor",
    "sInfoEmpty":      "Kayıt yok",
    "sInfoFiltered":   "(_MAX_ kayıt içerisinden bulunan)",
    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    "sInfoThousands":  ".",
    "sLengthMenu":     "Sayfada _MENU_ kayıt göster",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Yükleniyor...",
    "sProcessing":     "İşleniyor...",
    "sSearch":         "Ara:",
    "sZeroRecords":    "Eşleşen kayıt bulunamadı",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "|<",
        "sLast":     ">|",
        "sNext":     ">>",
        "sPrevious": "<<"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending":  ": artan sütun sıralamasını aktifleştir",
        "sSortDescending": ": azalan sütun sıralamasını aktifleştir"
    }
},
    rowReorder: {
            selector: 'td:nth-child(0)'
        },
        responsive: true,
        paging: "true",
        lengthMenu: [ [10, 15, 25, 50, 100], [10, 15, 25, 50, 100] ],

        aoColumns: [
        { "sWidth": "4%" },
        { "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "sWidth": "10%" },
        { "sWidth": "13%" },
        { "sWidth": "29%" },
        { "sWidth": "9%" },
        { "sWidth": "15%" }
    ],
     bAutoWidth: true,
     pagingType: "simple_numbers"
    });

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every(function () {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            if (that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: @Rasclatt I have found the bug and paste code here. so you know everything. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Rasclatt I asked a question. so?